# Finding the values and keys from dictionaries and verifying them

Tags: python

Given a dictionary:

```
data = [{'id':'1234','name':'Jason','pw':'*sss*'},
    {'id':'2345','name':'Tom','pw': ''},
    {'id':'3456','name':'Art','pw': ''},
    {'id':'2345','name':'Tom','pw':'*sss*'}]
```

I need to find that the always `pw` contains `''` or `*sss*`.

I tried doing this:

```
for d in data:
    if d['pw'] == ['*sss*' or '']
        print "pw verified and it is '*sss*' or '' "
    else:
        print "pw is not any of two'*sss*' or ''"
```

Please help me to complete this. I need to find that the always `pw` contains `' '` or `'*sss*'`.

If possible I need to do it in a single line.

Comment: "If possible I need to do it in a single line." Why?

Answer (score 4):

`['*sss*' or '']` returns `['*sss*']` because `''` is False and `*sss*` is considered True.

That means your list reads as `[True or False]`. And the `True` factor is chosen (in this case, the `*sss*`.

You probably meant to do something like:

```
if d['pw'] in ['*sss*', '']:
```

Or even:

```
if d['pw'] == '*sss*' or d['pw'] == '':
```

As a one liner (kinda):

```
>>> for res in ("pw verified and it is '*sss*' or '' " if i['pw'] in ['*sss', ''] else "pw is not any of two'*sss*' or ''" for i in data):
...     print res
... 
pw is not any of two'*sss*' or ''
pw verified and it is '*sss*' or '' 
pw verified and it is '*sss*' or '' 
pw is not any of two'*sss*' or ''
```

Comment: @user2558589 I have also added a one-liner solution (kind of one line)

Answer (score 1):

Use `set` to do it in **one single line**.

```
ans = {d['pw'] for d in data}.issubset({'','*sss*'})
```

`ans` is `True` if `d['pw']` is always `''` or `'*sss*'` else `False`

Comment: Or even `{d['pw'] for d in data} <= {'', '*sss*'}`

Comment: @Eric Wow ! That was good one. I didn't know subset symbols can be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a one liner, use the `all()` function.

```
>>> data = [{'id':'1234','name':'Jason','pw':'*sss*'},
    {'id':'2345','name':'Tom','pw': ''},
    {'id':'3456','name':'Art','pw': ''},
    {'id':'2345','name':'Tom','pw':'*sss*'}]
>>> all(elem['pw'] in ('', '*sss*') for elem in data)
True
```

For the `if` condition.

```
>>> "pw verified" if all(elem['pw'] in ('', '*sss*') for elem in data) else "pw not verified"
'pw verified'
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)